# whats the difference between the two switches in rpg maker mv?

Tags: rpg-maker-mv

I dont understand what is the difference between the top and bottom set of switches in rpg maker mv. Can someone please explain?

[image]

Comment: I googled it and found this: https://forums.rpgmakerweb.com/index.php?threads/switches-and-variables-part-one.348/

Comment: no thats just explaining what switches are it does not answer my question which is what is the difference between the 2 switches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no differences between them, there are two because you may need more than just one *switch*-based condition for your map events.

For example, you don't need to use a *switch* and a *variable* when a simple second *switch* would be enough - and there it is.

From the manual ([here's an online version](https://rmmv.neocities.org/)), in the *RPG Maker MV > Events > Map Event Settings* section:

> #### Conditions
>
> [...]
>
> [...] If multiple conditions are set, an
> event will only occur when all conditions are met.

Since you can select any condition you need, you can even pick the second *switch* condition only, it will work as if you chose the first one.

Comment: Thank you this was helpful and straight to the point.